# Event Viewer VB scripts

Tags: vbscript

I am sure it has been asked million times, but I can't seem to find an appropriate answer for my simple need.  I am looking for a VB script that would pull event viewer logs into one location, either emailed to me or place on let's say my computer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would use powershell.  Much more friendly to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's been solved a million times, but Chances are that people have solved it in ways that won't make you happy.

Your best bet is the [Microsoft Technet Script Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849.aspx) and it's [Script Center Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter).  With those you will find the pieces needed to do it yourself.  Another great resource is the "Windows 2000 Scripting Guide", a Microsoft Publication.  The physical book is huge but cheaply-found, but I think that MS offers an electronic copy freely.  ([Online Version here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692931).)

The pieces of code that you'd need to leverage are well-documented; Chances are that you just need to assemble the pieces!

But by all means, open-source what you do!